# Delegate events in BaseAdapter Android

Tags: android, baseadapter

When we use a BaseAdapter, is necessary create another class(ClassA) that invoke this class(MyBaseAdapter). If on the view to inflate in the BaseAdapter contains buttons and another controls that dispatch events, how to delegate those events to the ClassA?

I am working with buttons, but in the future i will add EditText and another controls, but i not want manage those events in the BaseAdapter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just makes the Activity implements the Listeners you and in the adapter register as listener your class.

```
ActivityA implements OnClickListener {

}


YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 YourAdapter(Context ctx,....)

 // Context is your activity
```

}

```
 button.setOnClickListener((ActivityA) ctx);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your question, but I'll try to answer what I think you're asking.

No you don't have to deal with events in your Class that extends BaseAdapter. You could always make a callback to the Fragment or Activity that holds your adapter.

So in the Adapter:

```
private OnButtonSelectedListener mListener;

    public interface OnButtonSelectedListener {
    void onButtonSelected();

}

public void setListener (OnButtonSelectedListener listener) {
mListener = listener;

}
```

// Then when the button is clicked call:

```
mListener.onButtonSelected();
```

// In your Activity or Fragment,

// Make sure the class implements OnButtonSelectedListener
// Then add unimplemented methods

// Where ever you instantiate your adapter, set the listener

```
coolAdapter = new CoolAdapter(mContext, listOfCoolStuff);
coolAdapter.setListener(this);
```

// Then fill in your method onButtonSelectedListener to handle whatever it is you want to do

```
private void onButtonSelected() {

//handle your event here!

}
```

Let me know if you have any questions or if I just didn't understand your question correctly. Good Luck!

Comment: The XML that inflate the BaseAdapter contains 2 button(See [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/843/capturadepantalla201304m.png/), i want manage the OnClickListener in the class that instance the BaseAdapter, no in the class that extends of BaseAdapter. You understand me?

Comment: I'm going to need more code and examples because I can't understand what you are saying. I'm sorry, I do want to help though!

Comment: Its easy, view the other response. Its declare the method "public void onClick(View v) {" in the same class(MyAdapter that extends of BaseAdapter), but i want create the same method, but in another class,which instance the class MyAdapter. You understand me now?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Adapter as a listener:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // if you are in fragment
            View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_settings_cell, null);
            Button btn = v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
            // your code

        }

    }
```

Just inflate your custom list item layout.

All the buttons will have the same id, but you can put the position parameter in the tag to know the exact button that been pressed.

Make this adapter inner class of your Class A, that has some method that you can activate from the adapter.

Comment: You manage the click event in the same class, i want manage those events in the class that instance MyAdapter, you understand me?